# Select as in laravel dummy column

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I am trying to fill a select query column with dummy data with laravel query builder. The raw sql would be something like this.

```
SELECT CustomerName, 'Empty' as  Address
FROM Customers;
```

In laravel

```
$customers  = DB::table('customers')
    ->select(CustomerName, ''Empty' as Address')->get();
```

or

```
$customers  = DB::table('customers')
    ->select(CustomerName, 'Empty as Address')->get();
```

sadly does not work.

Comment: Is `Empty` column name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel also offers the `->selectRaw()` method for this:

```
// If you have a `Customer.php` Model
$customers = Customer::selectRaw("CustomerName, 'Empty' as 'Address'")->get();

// If you don't have a `Customer.php` Model, or prefer the Builder
$customers = DB::table('customers')->selectRaw("CustomerName, 'Empty' as 'Address'")->get();
```

Simply omit `'` around columns (like `CustomerName`), and you should get the expected results.